# Valid phone number field in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-analytics

I am having customer data in csv file and in that I have one column phone number. I need to clean the phone number field. I am getting the phone number column value like below

98377657 (valid phone number)
6578 8765 (valid phone number)
467584 (discard)
5674839 (discard)

I want to use the phone number whose length is exactly 8 character so the valid output would be
98377657
6578 8765
How I can achieve this in Azure data factory. Please help and advise

Cleaning and validating the phone number data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that you want each phone number as a separate row in the output. You should be able to do this using a dataflow and the Derived Column transformation.

You can create a dataflow, using your csv as the source followed by a derived column transformation. You can name the column whatever you want, put the code `iif(regexMatch(trim(phoneNumber), '([0-9]{4} ?[0-9]{4})'), phoneNumber, null())` in the expression section should do the trick for cleaning (substituting phoneNumber for the name of your phone number column of course).

The regex check that there is exactly 8 digits, with the potential for one space between digits 4 and 5, in the string with any *trailing* whitespace removed. From there, you will need to connect to a sink (with the sink being connected to your required output).

Hopefully, this has helped!

EDIT: I've updated the answer to use regex

Comment: I have tried above function but it is considering the phone number 1234 5678 as invalid phone number. I want the space should consider as a valid number

Comment: @Sam I've now updated my answer to use regex to account for the potential space between digit 4 and 5. If you don't want trailing whitespace to be removed, you can get rid of the trim function